# Allocation failed - process out of memory error from large SQL query results

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, tedious

I'm using [Tedious](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious) and `RxJS` to run a SQL query against a SQL Server and emit the results with an `Observable`. This function defines this behavior:

```
export function msExecute(sql) {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    config.database.sams.requestTimeout = 60000;

    var connection = new mssql.Connection(config.database.sams, function (err) {
      var request = new mssql.Request(connection);
      request.stream = true;
      request.query(sql);
      request.on('row', row => {
        observer.next(row);
      });
      request.on('error', err => {
        observer.error(err);
      });
      request.on('done', () => {
        observer.complete();
        connection.close();
      });
    });
    connection.on('error', error => console.log(`mssql error == ${error}`));
  });
}
```

I have a SQL query that returns ~110k records that I want to process, but I get this error during execution:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

   27330 ms: Scavenge 1396.7 (1457.4) -> 1396.7 (1457.4) MB, 1.4 / 0 ms (+ 2.0 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
   28635 ms: Mark-sweep 1396.7 (1457.4) -> 1396.6 (1457.4) MB, 1304.9 / 0 ms (+ 2.9 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 2.0 ms) [last resort gc].
   29936 ms: Mark-sweep 1396.6 (1457.4) -> 1396.5 (1457.4) MB, 1300.3 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x4035aee3ac1 <JS Object>
    1: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [/home/njones/projects/test-forge/node_modules/orawrap/lib/connectionmanager.js:250] [pc=0x20cbecafa065] (this=0x4035ae04189 <undefined>,resolve=0x3896ea762871 <JS Function resolvePromise (SharedFunctionInfo 0x203f09a91f11)>,reject=0x3896ea762829 <JS Function rejectPromise (SharedFunctionInfo 0x203f09a91fb9)>)
    2: lib$es6$promise$$internal$$initiali...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I don't need all of the results I once, so a solution that chunks results into separate queries would work, I'm just not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you should utilize Node.js streams.  It's hard to give more specific advice, since it's not clear what you do with SQL query results.

Basically you should [pipe query results](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#user-content-pipe) to your own stream:

```
request.pipe(stream);
```

With streams your query result output will be paused from time to time to allow for results to be processed in small chunks without exhausting your system resources by one huge result.

Alternatively you can try reading directly from stream:

```
request.read();
```

Normally, streams operate on strings and buffers exclusively.  Streams that are in [object mode](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_object_mode) can emit generic JavaScript values other than buffers and strings.  Assuming your `request` is a stream in object mode, `read()` should return one row of a result.

Streams are very important yet somewhat tricky part of Node.js.  Check out [Stream Handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) for more info.

Comment: The `stream` that is passed to `.pipe()` is a writable stream, but you can only `pause` readable streams. Could you provide a bit more code on how to implement the pausing stream?

Comment: The stream to pipe to can be `writable`, `duplex` or `transform` stream. The point is that if you pipe, the data will not start flowing until it's ready to be consumed, so you don't need to pause explicitly. To start reading data use `readable.read([size])`. You can try to read straight from request stream nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size